# Android jetpack compose: Navigate through text fields

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-jetpack, register-transfer-level

I implemented a screen that has a lot of TextFields and I used the scaffold as a root layer.
Because I wanted my screen to be rtl, I used Composition Local provider().

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {}
```

My TextFields were on the screen like this:

B A

D C

and when I wanted to navigate through these TextFields:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
      onNext = { LocalFocusManager.current.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next) }
)
```

what I Expected to happend: A -> B -> C -> D

what happend: B -> A -> D -> C

(I used a Column for parent root but textfields have Row as Parent root two by two (the Rows are in Column))

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you layout them? Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PylypDukhov one Column as root (in Scaffold) and each text filed is in a box and each row has 2 textfields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.focusOrder` modifier to achieve this:

```
Column() {
    val (aFocus, bFocus, cFocus, dFocus) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }


    Row {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "A",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .focusOrder(aFocus) { next = bFocus },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "B",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .focusOrder(bFocus) { next = cFocus },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next)
        )
    }

    Row {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "C",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .focusOrder(cFocus) { next = dFocus },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next)
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "D",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .focusOrder(dFocus) { },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next)
        )
    }
}
```